# Подключение к базе данных oracle 11g

Tags: c#, oracle

Здравствуйте. Есть программа c# ASP.NET раньше была подключена к базе 11g xe. Удалил xe поставил полноценный 11g. Коннект не менял, почему то полетела ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот моя строка подключения:

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=orcl;User ID=Mydb;Password=111292;Unicode=True");
```

TNS не настраивал. Не знаю обязательно ли это? Просто подключение к базе я делал в sql developer без использования tns. Использовал basic подключение. Что не так я делаю?

Comment: а в tnsnames.dat вы ORCL прописали ?

Comment: @Mike нет TNS вообще не трогал. Это глобальное имя если не ошибаюсь, при установке oracle 11g указывал. SID вообщем. А где лежит tns.dat? Я только видел tns.ora

Comment: препутал, tnsnames.ora конечно. ошибка говорит о том, что orcl не описан

Comment: @Mike Да его там нет. В каком конкретно tns его прописывать? который в клиенте или в dbhome?

Comment: @Mike хотя в dbhome в tns он уже есть, вот как выглядит `ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )`

Comment: @Mike проблема решилась, просто нужно было скопировать tns-ник ещё и в клиент. Спасибо за подсказку.